# Considerations for making a grids design for webapps

Tags: css, web-applications, desktop-application, css-frameworks

I'm looking for considerations that I need to make and known pitfalls when designing a grid for a **Webapp** (so not necessarily typographical or webdesign grids).

I'm specifically interested in what the considerations arise from moving a desktop app to the web. Is there any documentation out there for (old-school) desktop application grids? I couldn't find any.

All my searches have led me to all known CSS frameworks (Bootstrap, Foundation, Semantic, Unsematic, 960, etc.) which are useful for designing websites, and e-commerce sites, but not directly for creating highly intricate one-page webapps that require (quite) a bit more than a 12 column fluid grid.

E.g. has anyone ever built their own 160-col grid where you can switch seamlessly between a guttered and non-guttered mode?

Any previous bodies of work or experiences would also be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
Allard

Answer (score 0):

try this framework ..so helpful to create grid ui http://shopify.github.io/dashing/